# if 文でエラー SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Tags: python

どこを間違えているのかわかりません、教えて下さい。

```
a=input("日本一高い山は？")
if　a=="富士山"：
   print("正解！")
elif a=="ふじさん"：
print("漢字で書いてみよう")
else:
  print("残念日本一高い山は「富士山」です。")


File "<ipython-input-20-34bcf552f01a>", line 2
    if　a=="富士山"：
      　^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Comment: エラーそのものは、メッセージのとおり`if`と`a`の間の空白が全角空白になっているためでしょう。そして @cubick さん回答指摘の全角文字があり、更に`print("漢字で書いてみよう")`の行のインデントが不足しています。

Answer (score 0):

if と elif の行で使われているコロン `:` の記号がそれぞれ全角 `：` になっています。
半角の `:` に修正してください。

全角のコロン：で検索した結果:

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]